# AFX_MANAGE_STATE causes multiple definitions error

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, mfc, mmc

I am refactoring a big legacy project. It used to link libraries within its source files via `#pragma comment(lib, "lib_name.lib")`.
Once I've moved `#pragma comment(lib, "mmc.lib")` from the `.cpp` file to `.vcxproj`, I started receiving multiple definitions linker error:

```
1>uafxcwd.lib(afxstate.obj) : error LNK2005: "public: __cdecl AFX_MAINTAIN_STATE2::~AFX_MAINTAIN_STATE2(void)" (??1AFX_MAINTAIN_STATE2@@QEAA@XZ) already defined in mmc.lib(apimfc.obj)
```

I couldn't find the unit which caused multiple definitions since it is generated by a macro `AFX_MANAGE_STATE` (which by itself was very hard to determine). Basically, I had to rebuild the project, each time incrementally adding units and uncommenting the code.

I thought that some header is to blame, but it happened to be not the case. I have stripped the project to a single .cpp file:

```
#include <afx.h>
#include <Windows.h>

struct SINODE;
struct IConsole;

// some .cpp file
HRESULT OnAlertsSettings(SINODE * lpNode, LPVOID lpParam, IConsole * lpConsole)
{
    AFX_MANAGE_STATE(AfxGetStaticModuleState()); // this exact line causes multiple definitions
    
    reurn S_OK;   
}
```

Linker: `mmc.lib`

How can I fix this?

Comment: I just created a project using the code you provided and it compiles and links just fine (as a DLL or as an EXE). Maybe we need more info on your project settings, linker includes, preprocessor directives ...

Comment: @AdrianMole I'll do further investigation on this part. I can't reveal details